# error cannot infer type arguments for node<>

Tags: java

When i try to create a Node, appear "error cannot infer type arguments for node<>"
why? I do not know why it could be

```
public class LinkedDoubleEndedQueue<T> implements DoubleEndedQueue<T> {

    private static class Node<E> {
        private E elem;
        private Node<E> next;
        private Node<E> prev;

        public Node(E x, Node<E> nxt, Node<E> prv) {
            elem = x;
            next = nxt;
            prev = prv;
        }
    }

    private Node<T> first, last;

@Override
public void addFirst(T x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Node<T> node = new Node<>();


}
```

Comment: Are you calling the correct constructor of Node? It would infer the type if you use the constructor that have E as argument

Answer (score 3):

The error you see is masking the fact that your `Node` constructor takes arguments, therefore the no-args constructor cannot be invoked.

When declaring a custom constructor in a class, the default no-args constructor is not automatically available anymore.

Either parametrize your constructor invocation with the required args (e.g. `t`, the next `Node`, the previous `Node`) or add a no-args constructor to the `Node` class.

Comment: Thank you Mena ,indeed that was the mistake